# Python for beginners

Tags: python-3.x

Python programming: I need to write a program that takes two inputs of military time. For example,(0900,1700) and output the time differences of the two input in numbers in hours, minutes

ex:

```
print("Enter the first time:") 0900
print("Enter the second time:") 1730
```

output

```
8 hours 30 minutes
```

And in the reverse order

```
print("Enter the second time:") 1730
print("Enter the first time:") 0900
```

output

```
15 hours 30 minutes
```

I have tried the code below, but the output was just my input.

```
import datetime,time

first = input("Enter the first time in military hours:")
second = input( "Enter the second time in military hours:")
first_t= datetime.time(hour=int(first[0:2]), minute=int(first[2:4]))
second_t= datetime.time(hour=int(second[0:2]), minute=int(second[2:4]))
hour = ( second.hour-first.hour )
minute= (second.hour-first.hour)
fmt = ("%H ,%M")
print (first_t.strftime(fmt) , second_t.strftime(fmt))
```

For the input values `0500,1830`, it gave me the output of `05 , 00 18 , 30`

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: how might i correct my code so that it outputs the correct answer

Comment: is this a homework problem?

Comment: Yes it is a homework problem from my IT210 programming class.

Comment: You're printing the input indeed in this line: `print (first_t.strftime(fmt) , second_t.strftime(fmt)`, since you're printing `first_t` and `second_t`, try to fix that

Comment: Thank you justhalf I have switch the print to print (hours,"hours",minutes,"minutes") but i do get a negative in the minutes if i put 00 in my second input hmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to python. In python everything is easy. Firstly you need to understand your problem on a slightly deeper level though. The problem here is just realizing that you're taking two slightly different sums. A good way to go about this would be to represent them both in a common form (minutes) then do all of your math there and change back only for display purposes. For example:

```
def time_diference(time1, time2):
    hour_change = abs(int(time1[:2]) - int(time2[:2]))
    minute_change = int(time2[2:]) - int(time1[2:])
    # Change hours to equivalent minutes so you're really comparing apples to apples
    total_minute_change = hour_change * 60 + minute_change
    return total_minutes_change

def print_time(minute_difference):
    # Display the answer back to the user

print_time(time_difference(first, second))
```

Now that you've got them compared and you have a difference you should have a better grasp of how to proceed, but there are still edge cases to think about.

For instance, what happens if you've got the times "0900" and "0845". In your original example you might want to think of another edge case, which is the case when you've got negative minutes, such as: `0945` and `1337`, in which case your solution breaks.

I'm trying hard not to spoonfeed you since this is the kind of stuff you really need to figure out largely on your own and since this is homework, but I hope this gives you a good place to start.

Comment: Well thank you for your answer, and the help from you other guys. This is my first programming class, so all of this is flying at me pretty quickly. I understand the variables in your answer, but not all of the placement. Thanks anyways.